# taking input from formatted Dialog box java

Tags: java

First I want to create a Dialog Box With 4 option:
"skip","replace","Skip all","Replace all"

Then I Want To check which buton has been clicked and work according to it.
How could I do so?

I try to make Dialog box with this But Can't check which button is clicked:

```
String[] choices={"Skip","Replace","Skip All","Replace all"};
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Want to skip File" , "Multiple Files", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
```

Comment: Where is your code? Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation from JOptionPane:

```
Returns:
an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog
```

It reurns 0  if "Skip" is pressed, 1 if "Replace" is pressed and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JOptionPaneTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] choices={"Skip","Replace","Skip All","Replace all"};
    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                           null                          // Center in window.
                         , "Want to skip File"           // Message
                         , "Multiple Files"              // Title in titlebar
                         , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION     // Option type
                         , JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE  // messageType
                         , null                          // Icon (none)
                         , choices                       // Button text as above.
                         , choices[0]                    // Default button's label
                       );
    switch (response) {
            case 0: 
                // Code for skip
                break;
            case 1:
                // Code for replace
                break;
            case 2:
                // Code for skip all
                break;
            case 3:
                // Code for replace all
                break;
            case -1:
                // Code for the close box(-1)
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                // Code to catch errors
        }
    }
}
```